# C scanf overwriting globally declared array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory, buffer, structure

I found out that my array of structs is getting overwritten when scanning string into buffer, I probably somehow share the same memory but I can't figure out how to fix it.

> Struct and array of structs global declaration

```
struct Node {
    int number;
    char *string;
};


struct Node nodes[50] = {{ 0 }};
```

... some operations with nodes in array ...

> insert function

```
void insert(char *string, int number)
{
nodes[lastIndex].number = number;
nodes[lastIndex].string = string;
```

> Now I scan string into buff

```
char buff[20]

while (scanf("%s", buff) > 0)
    {
        if (!strcmp(buff, "print"))
            printf("%s", printhighest());
        else
        {
            scanf("%s %d", buff, &number);
            insert(buff, number)
        }
    }
```

Everytime the first condition applies, the char* string, in the structure array gets overwritten with string "print" on every element of array.

It changes immidiately as the while loop starts after the `scanf("%s", buff)`

So when I want to print it looks something like this:

node[0]
    - number(10)
    - string("print") 

node[1] - number(25) - string("print") 

and so on...

And btw I can't change the while loop.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is not clear, what is `str`, do you allocate memory in for `nodes[...].string`?... Please post some [MCVE]

Comment: Basically I insert strings into nodes in array of nodes, if I type "insert string" in console, it will insert this string in specific node in the node array. But when I type "print" it should print the latest one. It does, however the char* string of latest one is "print"

Comment: This does not answer the questions in the comment. What is `str` and do you allocate memory for the `nodes[x].string` ? There is a reason why you should add a MCVE.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm not allocating any memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
nodes[lastIndex].string = string;
```

Be aware that `char*` is not a string per se, but actually only a pointer to some character array located somewhere in memory.

With above assignment, all nodes point to exactly the same memory location `buff`, thus all nodes see exactly the same text written there - which will get "print" when you finally want to print:

```
buff  <----------------
            |    |     |
nodes[0].string  |     |
      nodes[1].string  |
          nodes[2].string
            .
             .
              .
```

To solve the issue, you need to create new memory for the strings and copy the content of `buff` to; most easily done with [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) function:

```
nodes[lastIndex] = strdup(buff);
```

*Alternatively,* duplicate the string already outside:

```
insert(strdup(buff), number);
```

Be aware that `strdup` allocates new memory, so don't forget to free the strings again when not needed any more to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Yes I was not aware that I'm assigning just a pointer. Strdup() solves the issue, thanks.